# Check if a directory exists using the first 6 (or any) amount of characters

Tags: c#, system.io.directory

First post, zero programming history but learning on my own with google and Udemy classes.

I wrote a program that will create a bunch of project directories on our server. I need to check the first 6 characters of the current directories in the path to see if the project number has been used already (the directory is longer than 6 digits, but the first 6 are the project number, then the name of the project) cannot find any info on any site, including this one.

```
enter code here
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

/* Created on 1/7/2019 by James L. Miller
 * updated on 2/13/2019 to get the year automagically
**/
namespace MMEFolders
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // this sets the string for location and clears it
            string project = null;

            // this sets the current year
            string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

            // this sets the string for Server (and adds current Year variable)
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                project = @"\\mmejaxdc1\projects\" + year + "\\";
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                project = @"\\mmeatldc\projects\" + year + "\\";
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                project = @"\\mmecltdc\projects\" + year + "\\";
            }
            else if (radioButton4.Checked)
            {
                project = @"\\mmecltdc\raleigh\projects\" + year + "\\";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Location was Selected!");
                return;
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Code to create the folders here
            // this get the full project number
                var ProjectNo = textBox1.Text;
            // this addes the path to the server along with the project#
                var PathString = project + ProjectNo;

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // this cuts off everything after the project number
                var ProjNo = ProjectNo.Substring(0, 6);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //this checks the server code VS the selected server


            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //this checks the project number to see if it exists


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // this creates the DESIGN folder
        string subfolder1 = Path.Combine(PathString, (ProjNo + "_Design"));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1);
            // this copies the QAQC doc to the DESIGN folder
                foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"X:\2019\Do Not Delete\04\04"))
                File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(subfolder1, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
            // creates CUT SHEET folder under the DESIGN folder
            string subfolder1a = Path.Combine(subfolder1, (ProjNo + "_Cut Sheets"));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1a);
            // Creates the ELEC Folder under the DESIGN folder
                string subfolder1b = Path.Combine(subfolder1, (ProjNo + "_Elec"));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1b);
            // creates the FIREP Folder under the DESIGN folder
                string subfolder1c = Path.Combine(subfolder1, (ProjNo + "_FireP"));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1c);
            // creates the MECH Folder under the DESIGN folder
                string subfolder1d = Path.Combine(subfolder1, (ProjNo + "_Mech"));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1d);
            // this copys the file to the MECH Folder under the DESIGN folder
                foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"X:\2019\Do Not Delete\05\01"))
                File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(subfolder1d, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
            // creates the PLUMBING Folder under the DESIGN folder
                string subfolder1e = Path.Combine(subfolder1, (ProjNo + "_Plumbing"));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1e);
            // creates the QA QC Checklists Folder under the DESIGN folder
                string subfolder1f = Path.Combine(subfolder1, (ProjNo + "_QA QC Checklist"));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1f);
            // this creates the ELEC folder under QAQC folder under the DESIGN folder
                string subfolder1fa = Path.Combine(subfolder1f, "Elec");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1fa);
            // this copys the files to the ELEC folder under QAQC under the DESIGN folder
                foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"X:\2019\Do Not Delete\01\01"))
                File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(subfolder1fa, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1fa);
            // this creates the MECH folder under QAQC under the DESIGN folder
            string subfolder1fb = Path.Combine(subfolder1f, "Mech");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1fb);
            // this copys the files to the MECH folder under QAQC     
                foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"X:\2019\Do Not Delete\01\03"))
                File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(subfolder1fb, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
            // this creates the STRUCT folder under QAQC
                string subfolder1fc = Path.Combine(subfolder1f, "Struct");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1fc);
            // this copys the files to the STRUCT folder under QAQC
                foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"X:\2019\Do Not Delete\01\05"))
                File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(subfolder1fc, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
            // creates the Struct Folder
                string subfolder1g = Path.Combine(subfolder1, (ProjNo + "_Struct"));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1g);
            // this copys the files to the STRUCT Folder   
                foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"X:\2019\Do Not Delete\05\02"))
                File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(subfolder1g, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
            // this creates the SOILS folder under the Struct Folder
            string subfolder1ga = Path.Combine(subfolder1g, "Soils");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1ga);
            // creates the Tech Folder
                string subfolder1h = Path.Combine(subfolder1, (ProjNo + "_Tech"));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder1h);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // this creates the DWG folder
                string subfolder2 = Path.Combine(PathString, (ProjNo + "_Dwg"));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder2);
            // creates the ARCH folder under the DWG folder
                string subfolder2a = Path.Combine(subfolder2, "Arch");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder2a);
            // creates the ZIPS folder under the ARCH folder under the DWG folder
                string subfolder2aa = Path.Combine(subfolder2a, "Zips");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder2aa);
            // creates the CIVIL Folder under the ARCH folder under the DWG folder
                string subfolder2b = Path.Combine(subfolder2, "Civil");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder2b);
            // creates the REVIT FAMALIES Folder under the ARCH folder under the DWG folder
                string subfolder2c = System.IO.Path.Combine(subfolder2, "Revit Families");
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder2c);
            // creates the REVIT LINKS Folder under the ARCH folder under the DWG folder
                string subfolder2d = System.IO.Path.Combine(subfolder2, "Revit Links");
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder2d);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // this creates the EMAIL folder
                string subfolder3 = System.IO.Path.Combine(PathString, (ProjNo + "_Email"));
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder3);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //this creates the FINANCIALS folder
                string subfolder4 = System.IO.Path.Combine(PathString, (ProjNo + "_Financials"));
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder4);
            // this copys the files to the Financials folder
                foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"X:\2019\Do Not Delete\02\01"))
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, System.IO.Path.Combine(subfolder4, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)), true);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // this creates the MEETING NOTES Folder
                string subfolder5 = System.IO.Path.Combine(PathString, (ProjNo + "_Meeting Notes"));
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder5);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // this creates the PHOTOS folder
                string subfolder6 = System.IO.Path.Combine(PathString, (ProjNo + "_Photos"));
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder6);

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // this creates the RFI Folder
                string subfolder7 = System.IO.Path.Combine(PathString, (ProjNo + "_RFI"));
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder7);
            // this copys the files to the RFI folder
                foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"X:\2019\Do Not Delete\03\01"))
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, System.IO.Path.Combine(subfolder7, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)), true);

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // this creates the SHOPDWGS folder
                string subfolder8 = System.IO.Path.Combine(PathString, (ProjNo + "_ShopDwgs"));
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder8);
            // this copys the files to the SHOPDWGS folder
                foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"X:\2019\Do Not Delete\05\03"))
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, System.IO.Path.Combine(subfolder8, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)), true);


            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // this creates the SUBMITTAL folder
                string subfolder9 = System.IO.Path.Combine(PathString, (ProjNo + "_Submittal"));
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder9);
            // creates the ~MOST CURRENT DRAWINGS folder under the SUBMITTAL folder
                string subfolder9a = Path.Combine(subfolder9, "~Most Current Drawings");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder9a);

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // this creates the WORDPROC folder
                string subfolder10 = System.IO.Path.Combine(PathString, (ProjNo + "_WordProc"));
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder10);        
            // this creates the SITE VISIT Folder under the WORDPROC folder
                string subfolder10a = System.IO.Path.Combine(subfolder10, "Site Visit");
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder10a);
            // this copys the files to the SITE VISIT folder under the WORDPROC folder
                foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"X:\2019\Do Not Delete\04\05"))
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, System.IO.Path.Combine(subfolder10a, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
            // this creates the SITE VISIT Folder under the WORDPROC folder
                string subfolder10b = System.IO.Path.Combine(subfolder10, "Site Visit Reports");
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder10b);
            // this creates the Special Inspections Folder
                string subfolder10c = System.IO.Path.Combine(subfolder10, "Special Inspections");
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder10c);
            // this copys the files to the Special Inspections folder
                foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"X:\2019\Do Not Delete\05\05"))
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, System.IO.Path.Combine(subfolder10c, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
            // this creates the Specs folder
                string subfolder10d = System.IO.Path.Combine(subfolder10, "Specs");
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder10d);
            // this copys the files to the specs folder
                foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"X:\2019\Do Not Delete\05\06"))
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, System.IO.Path.Combine(subfolder10d, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
            // this creates the Status Folder
                string subfolder10e = System.IO.Path.Combine(subfolder10, "Status");
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder10e);
            // this creates the Transmittals folder
                string subfolder10f = System.IO.Path.Combine(subfolder10, "Transmittals");
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder10f);
            // this copys the files to the transmittals folder
                foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"X:\2019\Do Not Delete\04\02"))
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, System.IO.Path.Combine(subfolder10f, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)), true);

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // this clears the form
            // First the textbox
            textBox1.Text = null;
            // then the radio buttons
            var cntls = GetAll(this, typeof(RadioButton));
            foreach (Control cntrl in cntls)
            {
                RadioButton _rb = (RadioButton)cntrl;
                if (_rb.Checked)
                {
                    _rb.Checked = false;

                }
            }

            // this ends the activity and lets you know the folders were created
            MessageBox.Show("The Project Folders were created, Thank You!");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // This is for the preview
            // this sets the string for location and clears it
            string location = null;

            // get the current year
            string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

            // these are the radio buttons
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                location = @"\\mmejaxdc1\projects\" + year +"\\";
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                location = @"\\mmeatldc\projects\" + year + "\\";
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                location = @"\\mmecltdc\projects\" + year + "\\";
            }
            else if (radioButton4.Checked)
            {
                location = @"\\mmecltdc\raleigh\projects\" + year + "\\";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Location was Selected!");
                return;
            }
            // this reads the radio buttons and sets a location, then shows the preview of the path
            // based on the selection
            var tempproj = textBox1.Text;
            string FullPath = location + tempproj;
            MessageBox.Show(FullPath);

            // this ends the preview code users closes messagebox to end
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // this clears the form
            // textbox
            textBox1.Text = null;

            // radio buttons
            var cntls = GetAll(this, typeof(RadioButton));
            foreach (Control cntrl in cntls)
            {
                RadioButton _rb = (RadioButton)cntrl;
                if (_rb.Checked)
                {
                    _rb.Checked = false;

                }
            }
        }

        private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.TopMost = checkBox1.Checked;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control, Type type)
        {
            var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
            return controls.SelectMany(ctrls => GetAll(ctrls, type)).Concat(controls).Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

I tried this:

string newProjectNumber = PathString; // new project number you want to add
                DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(project);// sets folder path
                DirectoryInfo[] dirs = d.GetDirectories(); // get the full list of dirs inside path

```
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs) // iterating over dirs
            {
                string dirName = dir.Name;
                if (dirName.Substring(0, 6) == newProjectNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This folder already exists.");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Please show us your current setup (your code you have so far). We will not write code for you, but we indeed will help you solve issues with your code. Also, check out our [ask] topics.

Comment: Please add the code.

Comment: it says the code is too long to add, how else can I get it to you

Comment: *"the code is too long to add"* - see [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string newProjectNumber = "000006"; // new project number you want to add
      DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Test");//Assuming Test is your Folder
      DirectoryInfo[] dirs = d.GetDirectories(); // get the full list of dirs inside C:\Test

      foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs) // iterating over dirs
      {
        string dirName = dir.Name;
        if (dirName.Substring(0,6) == newProjectNumber)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("This folder already exists.");
        }
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

Comment: @JimMiller https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow

Comment: You may also use `if (dirName.StartsWith(newProjectNumber) { ... }`.

Comment: JoKeRxbLaCk - that did not work, I copied and paste the code into the program and it seems it couldn't get the variables from the code above it. I removed some of the elemts to let the variable pass down but that did not work either - thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Callum - my appologies, I am too new to programming that I would not know where that goes into the code to make it work, but I like the simplicity of one more line

Comment: @JimMiller this example should work. Did you have the directory `C:\Test` ?

Comment: I am using a real world setup, not a test folder. I changed the code to try to use the existing variables to the directory path and using the new directory name:

Comment: @JimMiller no matter which folder you are setting, it will work in every directory. I setted a test directory to show you how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Directory.EnumerateDirectories(string, string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratedirectories?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_EnumerateDirectories_System_String_System_String_) function can be used to search for folders in a directory that match a pattern. This function demonstrates an example of its use applicable to your scenario:

```
static bool DirectoryWithPrefixExists(string root, string prefix)
{
    return Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root, prefix + "*").Any();
}

bool existsAlready = DirectoryWithPrefixExists(@"C:\root\directory", projectNumber);
```